# Define custom class for object Swift

Tags: swift, macos

For example i have a `BaseObject` class:

```
class BaseObject: NSObject {
    let id:UInt64
}
```

And manager class for this objects:

```
public class Manager: NSObject {
    public var objs:[BaseObject] = []

    public func addObj(obj:BaseObject) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to create a library, and to allow developer set his own class that should inherit from `Base Object`

For example:

```
class MyOwnBaseObject: BaseObject {
   var ownProperty:Int = 0
}

var manager = Manager();
manager.objClass = MyOwnBaseObject
```

and `manager.objs` should now return: `[MyOwnBaseObject]` and `manager.addObj()` should work with `MyOwnBaseObject`

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the return type to be of the subclass you specified, you can use generics:

```
public class BaseObject: NSObject {
    let id:UInt64 = 0
}

public class MyOwnBaseObject: BaseObject {
    var ownProperty:Int = 0
}

public class Manager<T>: NSObject {
    public var objs:[T] = []

    public func addObj(obj:T) {
        objs.append(obj)
    }
}

var manager = Manager<BaseObject>()
let ob1 = BaseObject()
manager.addObj(obj: ob1)
let ob2 = BaseObject()
manager.addObj(obj: ob2)

var otherManager = Manager<MyOwnBaseObject>()
let ownOb1 = MyOwnBaseObject()
otherManager.addObj(obj: ownOb1)
let ownOb2 = MyOwnBaseObject()
otherManager.addObj(obj: ownOb2)


print(manager.objs)    // objs is of type [BaseObject]
print(otherManager.objs)   // objs is of type [MyOwnBaseObject]
```

Without generics, you code would still work, but you would need to cast any of the objects returned by `objs` to the custom class (such as `MyOwnBaseObject`) to access any subclass-specific properties.